(Outdated Implementations) I'm working on paying block authors in Proof Of Authority (POA)
I'm currently developing a private Substrate-based blockchain and working on implementing a mechanism to pay block authors (validators) in a Proof of Authority (PoA) consensus. I've been following a guide from this blog, but many of the pallets and functions used in the blog are outdated and incompatible with the newer version of Substrate that I am using.
My Cargo.toml file for the runtime looks like this:
Cargo.toml for Runtime

This is the updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641374/how-could-i-configure-the-reward-for-a-substrate-aura-validator
